# c++ inheritance Building method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a question about building a method :

```
virtual std::string getPerson() const;
```

I have a child class Player and a the parent is Person.

Class Player :

```
class Player : public Person {
public:
    Player(const std::string& p_name,const std::string& p_lastname, const int& p_age, const std::string& p_position);
    virtual ~Player();
    virtual Person* clone() const;

    std::string getPosition() const;
    virtual std::string getPerson() const;


private:
    std::string m_position;

};
```

Class Person :

```
    class Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string& p_name,const std::string& p_lastname, const int& p_age);
    virtual ~Person();

    virtual std::string getPerson() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getLastName() const;
    int getAge() const;


private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_lastname;
    int m_age;
};
```

When I try to add this in Player :

```
std::string Player::getPerson()
{
    ostringstream os;

        os << "Name         :" << getName() << "\n";
        os << "LastName     :" << getLastName()() << "\n";
        os << "Age          :" << getAge()() << "\n";
        os << "Position     :" << getPosition();

        return os.str();
}
```

I get Member declaration not found

I can't get it to work I would need to print something like this :

```
Name     : John
Lastname : Smith
Age      : 22
Position : Goalie
```

Comment: You have copied and pasted the class "Player" twice.

Comment: Please include your Person class to take a look at it... (you copied Player twice)

Comment: getPerson() is a really confusing function name. Why not just call it print()? Or even better, overload operator<< so it works with standard stream output.

Comment: Can't answer since you have not shown us the Person class, but have you thought of using delegation instead of inheritance?  That is, creating a Player class that has a reference to a Person instance instead of a Player that _is_ a Person.  Delegation generally is more powerful than inheritance (suppose you wanted a model where one person could be a player for more than one team?), although the down-side is that it sometimes makes you write more code in situations where inheritance would be good enough.

Comment: you are missing the `const`, the function definition should be `std::string Player::getPerson() const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the const at the end of the function signature. This should work:

```
std::string Player::getPerson() const
{
    ostringstream os;

        os << "Name         :" << getName() << "\n";
        os << "LastName     :" << getLastName()() << "\n";
        os << "Age          :" << getAge()() << "\n";
        os << "Position     :" << getPosition();

        return os.str();
}
```

But please mind what I said in the comment and change the function's name, or even better, make your class work with `std::ostream` by means of [overloading `operator<<`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/output-operator.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help and I renamed it print()

Answer (score 0):

Simple thing:

```
std::string getPerson() const;
```

is not the same as:

```
std::string getPerson();
```

If you can use c++11 use the override keyword, that protects you from such kind of mistakes. In your case the compiler detects the problem. But if you have other variants you maybe declare a new method instead of overloading!